# Nothing assign into array element in nodejs app

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I have a problem in my express project that I can't resolve since a day. I can't push some data into array element. Let me demonstrate my code and data.

**Here is my *result* data which coming from mongodb:**

```
result = {
   name: 'Workflow',
   steps:[
      { name: 'First Step',
        assignee: '2cb56eadab3fbdc46dcb896e2ec68f33'
      },
      {
        name: 'Second Step',
        assignee: '1h374jab3fbdc46wer896e2ec687as'
      }
    ],
   __v: 0 
}
```

**Here is my code block:**

```
var save = function(data, next) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        if (_.isEmpty(data._id)) {
            Workflow.create(data, function (err, result) {
                if (err) return next(err);

                result.steps.forEach(function(step) {
                    step.detail = {
                        fullName: 'blablabla',
                        avatar: 'blablabla'
                    }
                });
                resolve(result);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**After running code block my expectation is:**

```
result = {
       name: 'Workflow',
       steps:[
          { name: 'First Step',
            assignee: '2cb56eadab3fbdc46dcb896e2ec68f33',
            detail: {
                fullname: 'blablabla',
                avatar: 'blablabla'
            }
          },
          {
            name: 'Second Step',
            assignee: '1h374jab3fbdc46wer896e2ec687as',
            detail: {
                fullname: 'blablabla',
                avatar: 'blablabla'
            }
          }
        ],
       __v: 0 
    }
```

I can't get my expectation from result data and can't understand why detail is not assign steps array elements?

Comment: Not able to see where you tried to push element into Array.

Comment: Too many grammar mistakes, unable to understand what you are trying to say and do.

Comment: It is simple actually first block is my data and last block is what I want to see after  run the code (second block) @NAVIN

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly modify the objects that MongoDB gives you, they're frozen.

You can *copy* the object and assign to the copy:

```
const copy = {...result, steps: result.steps.map(step => {
    const stepCopy = {...step};
    stepCopy.detail = 
        fullName: 'blablabla',
        avatar: 'blablabla'
    };
    return stepCopy;
})};
resolve(copy);
```

That can actually be written more concisely, but it starts getting hard to read:

```
const copy = {...result, steps: result.steps.map(step => (
    {...step, detail: {
        fullName: 'blablabla',
        avatar: 'blablabla'
    }}
)};
resolve(copy);
```

Or, since I notice you're using ES5 syntax (but presumably with polyfills):

```
var copy = Object.assign({}, result);
copy.steps = copy.steps.map(function(step) {
    var stepCopy = Object.assing({}, step);
    stepCopy.detail = {
        fullName: 'blablabla',
        avatar: 'blablabla'
    };
    return stepCopy
)};
resolve(copy);
```

You'll need a polyfill for `Object.assign` (or I see Underscore/Lodash in your code, you can use [`_.extend`](https://underscorejs.org/#extend) instead, you literally just replace `Object.assign` with `_.extend` in the above).

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answer. I tried your answer but result not changed.

Comment: Here my modified code block according to your answer. Am I missing something?      `Workflow.create(data, function (err, result) {
        if (err) return next(err);                
           var copy = _.extend({}, result);
             copy.steps = copy.steps.map(function(step) {
                   var stepCopy = _.extend({}, step);
                   stepCopy.detail = {
                       fullName: 'blablabla',
                       avatar: 'blablabla'
              };
               return stepCopy;
           });
           resolve(copy);
       });`

Comment: @SerhatTAN - That looks right. I guess there must be something else wrong. :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in another way. Add detail object in the model itself. Set default value in the model definition.